# Is there any dynamic way of changing the proxy target in React JS (or any other Front-end JS), without restarting the application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Is there any dynamic way of changing the proxy target in React JS, without restarting the application?

I have multiple node JS servers in the local intranet (which Uses Private IPs, with No concept of deploying using public IP).
And I have one GUI using React JS, which will handle/manage multiple node JS servers.

Using one proxy settings configuration in package.json serves only one NodeJS server, If I update package.json with the next target in proxy, I need to restart the app again.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Is this something you are trying to do in a production build? Or just something to reduce local development cycle?

Comment: Hi @DecPK, I have set the proxy: "https://IP_ADDRESS:Port" in the package.json and tried adding the middleware by configuring setupProxy.js. Both cases are working fine and are able to get the proper output. But it's only for a single node server, if I want to add the other node server in the existing UI, I need to edit above files and restart of application is needed

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I tried in both dev and production build

Comment: If you need to communicate with more than one backend you may just need to handle switching between baseUrls manually in the app code instead of at build time via the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems to be a bad idea to do so. You should have a stable / static proxy. Changing the proxy dynamically will cause many issues in your application.

- you will have to handle n/w issues
- you will have to handle white-listing/black-listing issues
- assets loading issues and many other.

Still, if you want to try:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Check this URL.

This code worked for **React 16.8.13**

- delete `"proxy": {***}` from `package.json` file
- type `npm install http-proxy-middleware`
- create the file `src/setupProxy.js`
  -insert the code as following:

src/setupProxy.js

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/endpoint/*', {
            target: 'http://address/',
            secure: false,
        }),
    );
};
```

src/proxy-config.properties

```
end.point='/endpoint/*'
target='http://address/'
secure=false
```

And then, you need to change the above code to get the current proxy from a file / DB as follows.

- With some code, check whether the proxy is working or not
- If not, get new proxy from the file/DB
- With you NODE code (or manually), keep changing the proxy-config.properties file.